# Comparison between Timestamp and date giving error ora-01852

Tags: sql, oracle, date, timestamp

There is one table which has date column of type varchar2. The format of values in this field is : 2013-12-19T12:12:23.345000000Z
I have to find the difference between two successive dates. But as the dates are in string format, I first convert it to timestamp. I use following query for the same.

```
 select dccontextid,
        to_timestamp(substr(cdate,1,10)||' '||substr(cdate,12,12),'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff')
   from cam6eng.ttestcolorproc_wd
  where to_timestamp(substr(cdate,1,10)||' '||substr(cdate,12,12),'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff') between :StartDate and :EndDate
```

If the above query is run without including where clause, it shows proper timestamp values. But the moment I put where clause, it gives error ORA-01852 Seconds must be between 0 and 59.
(This is because some records have second=59 and fraction=some nonzero value)

What can be a workaround for this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp conversion seems to be ok:

```
select to_timestamp(substr('2013-12-19T12:12:23.345000000Z', 1, 10) || ' ' ||
                    substr('2013-12-19T12:12:23.345000000Z', 12, 12)
                   ,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff')
  from dual
```

The problem may be with the values you are comparing the timestamp with. :Startdate and :Enddate. What kind of values do you put in for those?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
StartDate and EndDate take format 19-DEC-2014 6:00:00 or 
19-12-14 06:00:00 or 19.12.14 06:00:00

I have tried with suggested method, but that too didn't work out.. 
:(

Comment: Ok, well maybe the timestamp conversion is correct for the string you put in the question but maybe some records in your table have incorrectly formatted timestamp strings.

Comment: Heyy! Thanks!! Found the cause. The format is not the same throughout... VARCHAR2 datatype is causing the problem.